# Python aiohttp web server: connection refused

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiohttp

I'm implementing an asynch Python app which handles requests coming in on a web socket (port 9000) and regular web requests on 8000. The web socket code is working fine.

**Issue:** Http requests respond with "Connection refused"

Thank you!

```
async def create_http_server():
    app = web.Application()
    app.add_routes([web.get("/", home_page),
                    web.get("/ping", ping)])

    # https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_advanced.html#application-runners
    runner = web.AppRunner(app)
    await runner.setup()
    site = web.TCPSite(runner, "localhost", 8000)
    print ("Web server active on 8000")
    return site

async def home_page(request):
    """ HTTP handler for home_page. """
    return web.Response(text="Hello world!")

async def ping(request):
    """ HTTP handler for ping. """
    return web.Response(text="Pong baby!")

async def main():
    csms = CentralSystem()

    websocket_server = await create_websocket_server(csms)
    http_server = await create_http_server()

    ws_task = asyncio.create_task (websocket_server.wait_closed())
    web_task = asyncio.create_task (http_server.start())
    await asyncio.wait([ws_task, web_task])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: I'm not too clear what's going wrong, but you don't need to wait on `site.start()` given that it should return almost immediately. Also, you're missing the `runner.cleanup()` call that should be used to shut down the app at the end.